# I don't know how to place Get Theme Mod

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a wordpress theme and i am trying to add the cutomizer feature.
I want to change to the text only using customizer, otherwise it should be set to default. The section gets added to the customizer but not affecting the text. I wat to change powered by wordpress and other options of footer.
Below is the code i have.

```
<footer id="ob-footer" class="site-footer" <? echo get_theme_mod('footer');?> >
    <div class="site-info" >
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'https://wordpress.org/', 'openblogger' ) ); ?>">
            <?php
            /* translators: %s: CMS name, i.e. WordPress. */
             printf(  esc_html__( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'openblogger' ), 'WordPress' );
            ?>
        </a>
        <span class="sep"> | </span>
            <?php
            /* translators: 1: Theme name, 2: Theme author. */
            printf( esc_html__( 'Theme: %1$s by %2$s.', 'openblogger' ), 'openblogger', '<a href="https://websiteguider.com">WebsiteGuider</a>' );
            ?>
    </div><!-- .site-info -->
</footer>
```

I don't know what to do to make it happen. The customizer code looks like:

```
    /**
* Create site footer Setting and customise Control
*/
function your_theme_new_customizer_settings($wp_customize) {
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'hellop' , array(
        'title'    => __( 'Site Footer', 'openblogger' ),
        'priority' => 30
    ) );
// add a setting for the site footer text
$wp_customize->add_setting('footer');
// Add a control to change text
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'footer',
array(
'label' => 'Update Text Here',
'section'  => 'hellop',
'settings' => 'footer',
) ) );
}

add_action('customize_register', 'your_theme_new_customizer_settings');
```

Comment: If you solve this problem then put you answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You all of you guys, no one answered and now i solved it of my own